# C: Dynamic 2Dmatrix deallocation

Tags: c, memory, dynamic, matrix, free

How do i free this n*n matrix?

```
   int(*matrix)[n] = malloc(n*sizeof(*matrix));
```

i tried this:

```
   for(i=0 ; i<n ; i++) 
       free(matrix[i]);
```

After 1st iteration end, looking at debug values it seems that all memory has been freed, in fact in the 2nd iteration (i=1) debug gives me an error, i thought that this looked like losing the pointer to the head of a list so i tried to iterate from n-1 to zero, but it happened the same...

Comment: Are you sure you allocating enough space? look http://www.bestsolveerror.com/1173310/dynamic-allocationdeallocation-2d-3d-arrays/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling `malloc` once, so you must call `free` once:

`free(matrix);`